# How do I specify a specific prettier version in a VSCode .devcontainer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

### Background

In a repo, we have a pre-commit configuration that requires version 2.2.1 of prettier:

```yaml
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-prettier
    rev: "v2.2.1"
    hooks:
      - id: prettier
```

And in my `.devcontainer` I specify use of prettier, so that my code gets formatted on save:

```js
{
  // ...
  "settings": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    // ...
  }
}
```

Prettier is installed by the vscode extension, not globally, so doing:

```
npm list -g | grep prettier
```

in my dev container doesn't list anything installed.

### The problem

A different version of prettier is being used, and I get a conflict in how it formats arrays in json files. Every time I open up a particular json file, it gets reformatted by my editor.

Also, if I rebuild my devcontainer, I'm then liable to unknowingly switch the version of code formatter I use, leading to git hell.

### The question

How can I specify that my `devcontainer` use an exact prettier version so I can enforce the same behaviour in my dev environment as in our code quality tools?

### I have already tried this:

You can set up the prettier extension to use a resolved version of prettier, according to the instructions under "Prettier Resolution" [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode).

So I added to the Dockerfile:

```
# Ensure prettier is installed globally so the esbenp.prettier-vscode can find a specific version
# as discussed here:
#   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode
# NB You can remove the -g flag if you have a node project. I install globally because I use prettier on all projects, whether they have a node_modules folder or not.
RUN npm install prettier@2.2.1 -g -D --save-exact
```

And in the `.devcontainer.json` settings, told the extension to resolve the prettier module instead of using its own:

```
{
  // ...
  "settings": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "prettier.resolveGlobalModules": true,
    // ...
  }
}
```

That didn't work so I also tried adding:

```
    "prettier.prettierPath": "$(npm root -g)/prettier",
```

Which also didn't work; the prettier extension is still using it's own version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the version in the .devcontainer like this:

```
"extensions": ["esbenp.prettier-vscode@8.0.1"],
```

The trick is you also have to turn off extension automatic updates:

```
"settings": {
    "extensions.autoCheckUpdates": false,
    "extensions.autoUpdate": false
},
```

**Note: This turns off automatic updates for all extensions.**

Also, `RUN npm install prettier@2.2.1 -g -D --save-exact` in the Dockerfile adds the prettier CLI to the environment, not the VS Code extension.

Comment: Thanks @cwalvoort. I'd previously solved this by installing the correct version directly in my devcontainer `Dockerfile`, which is a great approach when you want a consistent stack (I build and push a devcontainer to dockerhub). But, I think this answer is most correct here.

Comment: Turning off automatic updates for all extensions is a pretty huge drawback that will _certainly_ cause more trouble than it's worth down the line.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin will automatically use the Prettier version installed in the current project. More info on the official repository: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#prettier-resolution

#### Best solution: install Prettier into your project

If your project uses Prettier, then Prettier should be one of its dependencies:

```bash
npm install --save-dev prettier
```

This is how you can strictly control which version a project uses.

#### Solution for occasional formatting

If you want to use Prettier on random files, you can ask it to use the version you installed globally

```bash
npm install --global prettier
```

And then set the setting in VS Code

[image: Prettier: Resolve Global Modules]

#### Solution for pre-commit users

I [asked for more solutions](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/3280) on their repo, but for now you could choose one of the two above.

Comment: Please see the "I have already tried this" section of the question.